# Passing a parameter from one thread to another in Jmeter

Tags: multithreading, parameters, jmeter

In Jmeter ,When logging in an application, Parameters like Viewstate are generated. I need to use this parameter in my next thread. ( I am not passing a variable but a parameter that has a "NAME" and "Value"). Can someone help please?!!

Comment: It would be useful to provide a minimal code snippet that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can extract the parameter using regular expression extractor as :

[image]

2. Then use BeanShell Assertion to make that variable global.

[image]

3. use the variable wherever you want using __property function.
   ${__property(devicegroup_id)}

Comment: Thanks Kishore. But i am onot getting the part in Regular expression where exactly i specify the Parameter name "_ViewSTATE"

Comment: As i have other paremeters to be passed.

Comment: can you please elaborate your problem with screenshot ??